# No video signal when passing through gpu in qemu/kvm

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am following this guide: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/ and I have made it successfully to step 5 when it comes time to startup up the VM. When I try to run qemu I get a window that pops up for qemu but I also get a message that says VFIO 0000:01:00.0 BAR 3 mmap unsupported. Performance may be slow. The guide says at this point I should be able to turn on the monitor connected to the passed through gpu and see a black screen with some yellow text on it, however I get no video signal at all.

I've checked to make sure that my iommu groups are good and according to the wiki on arch linux "Not all PCI-E slots are the same. Most motherboards have PCIe slots provided by both the CPU and the PCH. Depending on your CPU, it is possible that your processor-based PCIe slot does not support isolation properly, in which case the PCI slot itself will be appear to be grouped with the device that is connected to it." Which is the case for me, but they also say "This is fine so long as only your guest GPU is included in here" which is again the case for me. So I don't think that is the problem.

I've got this up in front of me on an extra computer while I'm trying to figure this out so replies should be fast for any info you may need from me. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.